# How can I obtain (even by coding a new function) the size of an Object array (type Fraction created by me)?

Tags: java, arrays, size

I am creating a function library for the class `Frazione` (it means fraction) and I need to work on the logical size of an array of type `Frazione`. How can I obtain it?

I tried a for loop and a while loop but I can't find the right way to separate the used indexes from the unused ones.

```java
public static int size(Frazione[] set) {
   int size = 0;
   for (int i = 0; i < set.length; i++)
      if (set[i] != null) //the only way I know not to count unused indexes
         size++;
   return size;
}
```

It should return the number of elements in the array but it doesn't even run

Comment: _it doesn't even run_. Why it doesn't run? What error do you have?

Comment: Um, maybe I could use an array to check if the spot is taken by putting 1 where it's taken and 0 when it's free, but I think it's too complicated and it might not work...

Comment: @Ruslan that the two types are incompatible (null is int and Frazione is different)

Comment: If you are trying to count the number of elements in `set` that are not `null`, then your code looks correct. What exactly are you trying to achieve and what is the problem with your current solution?

Comment: @dave now it runs correctly, I don't know what was the problem...
Do you have any idea of an alternate method without going through the whole array?

Answer (score 0):

Your code works fine. Just as an alternate you could do the same using stream API. There is [`count()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#count--) method that returns `long` type. So you could cast it to `int`:

```
public static int size(Frazione[] set) {
    return (int)Arrays.stream(set)
            .filter(Objects::nonNull)
            .count();
}
```

Comment: I didn’t learn it yet so I don’t really know how to use it, but thanks anyway!